# shift by partition using groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with one column I would like to shift, but over partition rather than the whole dataframe.

For example, I would like to go from this dataframe:

```
State, Year, GDP
NY,2011,100
NY,2012,110
NY,2013,120
CA,2011,70
CA,2012,80
CA,2013,90
```

to this dataframe:

```
State, Year, GDP, GDP y-1
NY,2011,100,NaN
NY,2012,110,100
NY,2013,120,110
CA,2011,70,NaN
CA,2012,80,70
CA,2013,90,80
```

So far I've used code like this:

```
grouped = df.groupby("State")
for state, state_df in grouped:
    state_df["GDP Y-1"]=state_df["GDP"].shift(1)
```

I believe this gives me what I want for each State, but then I don't know how to combine it back together (basically just appending each dataframe below one another). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your intermediate DataFrames in a list and use `pd.concat` to join them together:

```
grouped = df.groupby("State")
L = []
for state, state_df in grouped:
    state_df["GDP Y-1"]=state_df["GDP"].shift(1)
    L.append(state_df)

pd.concat(L)
Out[149]: 
  State  Year  GDP  GDP Y-1
3    CA  2011   70      NaN
4    CA  2012   80       70
5    CA  2013   90       80
0    NY  2011  100      NaN
1    NY  2012  110      100
2    NY  2013  120      110
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

The line below does the task

```
df['GDP Y-1'] = df.groupby('State')['GDP'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(1))
```

I see the question is asked about 2 years ago but the answer might help someone else